# Most used tags - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a blog. Now I want to display the most used tags of an author. The tags are stored in the articles table, in a column called tags, komma seperated:

Article table (id | authorid | tags):

1  | 1        | soccer, sport
2  | 1        | sport, tennis, injury
3  | 1        | sport, golf, injury

So I want to display author with id 1 and display his 3 most used tags (from the article table as displayed above). In this case that would be: sport, injury, soccer.

Is this possible in MySql?

Comment: Are you stuck with the denormalized `tags` column, or could you create an actual table listing article tags? With a table of tags this would be trivial.

Comment: You should really add a table for your tags and a table combining articles and tags, that would make it easy in mysql, now it´s going to be very hard if it´s even possible.

Comment: Yes, I figured. I'm stuck with this column for now. So is this even possible to do?

Comment: How is 'soccer' more used than 'tennis' or 'golf'? All three only appear once. What breaks the tie?

Comment: @Marc B: Probably native order of rows.

Comment: I like soccer more than tennis of golf. :) No, your right, it's a tie. should have mentioned soccer one more time.

Comment: Perhaps you could count the number of occurrences using regular expressions, see http://blog.anupamgupta.info/2010/04/need-explode-like-function-in-mysql-you-can-do-it-using-regexp/ , but if the database is not too big, I would resort to php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes its possible, but the better answer would be to direct you into a more "[Normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)" database structure.

You really need a db set up like:

Table of `articles`, table of `tags`, table of `article_tags` containing the IDs of the tag and the article it's assigned to.

You can then query the tags by each article ('X') by looking in `article_tags` and returning all `tag_id`'s where `article_id = ('X')`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to build this in. Makes a lot more sense.

Comment: No problem - often when looking at these types of problem, if it isn't easy to achieve there is something wrong with your data model.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) -- the wikipedia article is very advanced however it will give you terminology which you can search for to find more articles on the topic.

The basic idea is you'll have another table:

```
table name: tags
columns: id | name
```

And then a table to join them:

```
table name: article_tags
columns: article_id | tag_id
```

Then you'll [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) all of the data together in a query in order to display the tag names for each article.  It will then be possible to do more advanced queries on the tables to figure out things such as most used tag by article, and most used tag by author.